# Javacript Trouble looping through an Array of object using forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, foreach

It doesn't look like I'm able to loop through items at all.
Was expecting something like this `['in', 'STE-00004']` as output
code

```js
var sales_orders = ['in'];
    var count = 0;
var items = [
    {name: "STE-00004", sales_order_no: "SAL-ORD-2021-00005"},
    {name: "STE-00003", sales_order_no: "SAL-ORD-2021-00004"},
    {name: "STE-00002", sales_order_no: "SAL-ORD-2021-00004"},
]

items.forEach(function(item){
        if(sales_orders.indexOf(item.name) == -1){
            count++;
            sales_orders.push(item.name);
            console.log(sales_orders);
            console.log(count);
        }
    });
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What doesn't work? The code gets all the unique `item.name` values. Do you expect it to do something else?

Comment: The goal is to get the unique item.name & their count but it doesn't work

Comment: If i understand you correctly, mainly your `console.log` statements are misplaced. They should occur after the loop, not inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the desired output you need to use empty `array` and when you push use `['in',value]`

```js
var sales_orders = [];
var count = 0;
var items = [{
    name: "STE-00004",
    sales_order_no: "SAL-ORD-2021-00005"
  },
  {
    name: "STE-00003",
    sales_order_no: "SAL-ORD-2021-00004"
  },
  {
    name: "STE-00002",
    sales_order_no: "SAL-ORD-2021-00004"
  },
]

items.forEach(function(item) {
  if (sales_orders.indexOf(item.name) == -1) {
    count++;
    sales_orders.push(['in', item.name]);

  }
});
console.log(sales_orders);
```

Comment: What's the point of `sales_orders.indexOf(item.name)` in this case?

Comment: We don't know if `sales_orders`  will always empty

Comment: If `sales_orders` is a 2D array, the `indexOf` will always return -1

Comment: "if", assumes we don't know :)

Comment: What? You are creating a 2D array. If OP hasn't provided a [mcve], vote to close.

Comment: Was to get the unique item.name , i guess your work around might solve my problem

Comment: @adiga the example is in the question, it was not put in the tool. Obviously we have solved the part of how to get to the 2D Array the OP will continue on its own I think not? Or he will pay an agency or why not one of us to continue :)

Comment: @SalimMaftah your code already gets unique `item.name` values with a `'in'` at the beginning of the array. What's the issue?